# XSLT if Last node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my XSLT 1.0 code:

```
<xsl:for-each select = "segment">
    <xsl:if test ="position() != 1 or position() != last()">
      <notfirstorlast></notfirstorlast>    
     </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

This should add a `<notfirstorlast>` element that in all of the `<segment>` nodes exepct for the first and last. But its not working. It will work without the or statement. 
This Works:

```
<xsl:if test ="position() != 1>
```

Something is wrong with my or statement.

Comment: You seem to never accept answers, even if they solve your problem. On Stackoverflow, one way of saying "thank you" is to _accept_ an answer. Here, that means marking the tick on the left of an answer so that it appears in green. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Both of these conditions must be met, so you'll have to use "and" instead of "or":

```
<xsl:if test ="position() != 1 and position() != last()">
```

> Something is wrong with my or statement.

Yes, exactly. With an "or", *all* elements qualify for the `notfirstorlast` element because *all* elements are either "not the first" or "not the last" element.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <segment/>
    <segment/>
    <segment/>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:for-each select = "segment">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test ="position() != 1 and position() != last()">
      <notfirstorlast></notfirstorlast>    
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<segment/>
<segment>
   <notfirstorlast/>
</segment>
<segment/>
```